# Tkinter Canvas Objects

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In my python program, I have a tkinter canvas with a circle inside and I would like to create smaller circles but they need to be inside the big circle without touching it. Is there an easy way to do that other than using a while loop to check for collision each time.

This is an example of what I have currently:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Canvas
import random as r

root=Tk()

canv=Canvas(master=root,width=80,height=80)
circ1=canv.create_oval(2,2,78,78)
canv.pack()


for x in range(6):   #Inside this for loop is where I am struggling
  x=r.randint(0,60)
  y=r.randint(0,60)
  canv.create_oval((x,y,x+20,y+20),outline="black",fill="green")

root.mainloop()
```

Here, the code creates 6 small green circles randomly on the canvas but what I would like is for them all to be inside the outer circle without touching it. In theory, they should all be clearly visible as one of the tactics of the game I'm trying to recreate is to count the number, but that doesn't matter too much.

Comment: How should the smaller circles be arranged?

Comment: In this situation, it doesn't matter as long as they can all be seen

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] to show what you want to do and clarify the issue you came across.

Comment: Hopefully added something helpful

Comment: The distance between the center of small circle and that of big circle should be less than the difference of radii (call it `r`) of the two circles.  So you can calculate the (x, y) using a random value within zero and `r` and a random angle between zero and 360.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import random as r
import math

root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(master=root, width=80, height=80)
circ1 = canv.create_oval(2, 2, 78, 78)
canv.pack()

circle_radius = 38 
small_circle_radius = 10
for _ in range(60):
    angle = r.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi) # 2pi = 360deg
    distance = r.uniform(small_circle_radius, circle_radius - small_circle_radius)  

    x = 40 + distance * math.cos(angle)
    y = 40 + distance * math.sin(angle)

    canv.create_oval((x - small_circle_radius, y - small_circle_radius, x + small_circle_radius, y + small_circle_radius), outline="black", fill="green")

root.mainloop()
```

- The `distance * math.cos(angle)` gives how far the smaller circle's center should be horizontally from the big circle's center.
- And, adding `40`([image] or radius of big circle) to it shifts this position to the canvas's center.

### 6 circles

[image]

### 60 circles

[image]